# Show a div style with css next to the field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a laravel nova cms. And I have a Gradient resource. One of the Gradient fields is the css property

```
 Text::make('CSS property, 'css_property')->rules([
                'required'
            ])->sortable(),
```

This is working. However both in the index page of the Gradient resource and on the edit page I would like to show like a div with the gradient value defined in this field so its possible to have a small visual how the gradient looks like. Like show the column value "linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);" and at right of this value show a small square with the preview of the gradient. Something like this:
[image]

Do you know how to properly achieve this in nova?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create custom field

Comment: It seems that is also possible like this: Text::make('CSS Property', 'css_property', function () {   
                $gradient = DB::table('gradients')->where('id', $this->id)->first();
                return "<div style='background: ". $gradient->css_property ."'></div>";
            })->asHtml(). However like this it appears correct on the index page but not on the details/create page, it appears like the html content on the fields.